# How to stop user input interrupting "ScrollIntoView" whilst in progress

Tags: javascript, html, dom, user-experience

### Context

I am creating a site where there are sections stacked in rows, and each row takes up the full viewport.

I don't want the site to be scrollable normally, and would instead like the site to "snap" to the bottom of each section, so that I can then play out the animations taking up the full view port.

### Issue

I took the approach of listening to scroll events, and then triggering a `nextsection.ScrollIntoView` when the user had scrolled far enough to snap to the next view.

This doesn't work well though, as the `ScrollIntoView` is interupted by user scroll activity, including the latent scrolling of the mouse that hangs around for about 300ms after you've scrolled.

I managed to get it *sort of* working by using a `setTimeout(scrollIntoView(), 400)`, but this takes too much time and relies on the user not interacting with the site after scrolling.

I made a CodePen ([here](https://codepen.io/rejesto/pen/vYjrByM)) showing the type of setup I'm working with, however to see the issue you need to open it as a webpage itself, as CodePen doesn't perform a smooth animation when using `ScrollIntoView` and just jumps there.

I need a **smooth** and **uninterruptable** animation as the site switches from one section to another, but as of yet I've found no working ways to implement this.

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.